Error when execute pyinstaller with --windowed app.pyw command
When i perform the command bellow, i get this error:
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed app.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.pyw", line 1, in <module>
    import eel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

My python script:
import eel
import pyperclip

eel.init('app/www')

total_seconds = 0

@eel.expose
def converter_tempo(minutes, seconds):
    total_seconds = (minutes * 60) + seconds
    pyperclip.copy(total_seconds)
    return total_seconds

eel.start('index.html', size=(480, 730))

My HTML/JS script:
<template>
  <div class="page" data-name="home">
    <!-- Top Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-large">
      <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
      <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
        <div class="title">Conversor Minutos/Segundos</div>
        <div class="title-large">
          <div class="title-large-text">Conversor Minutos/Segundos</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Toolbar-->
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom">
      <div class="toolbar-inner">
        <a href="#" class="link" @click="${fecharApp}">Fechar</a>
        <a href="#" class="link convert-form-to-data">Converter</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Scrollable page content-->
    <div class="page-content">
      
      <form class="list list-strong-ios list-dividers-ios list-outline-ios" id="formDados">
        <ul>
          <li class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-content item-input width-100">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-label">Minutos</div>
                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                  <input type="number" name="minutes" placeholder="Informe os minutos" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-content item-input width-100">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-label">Segundos</div>
                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                  <input type="number" name="seconds" placeholder="Informe os segundos" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
      <div id="resultado" class="block border-color-primary"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default (props, { $, $on, $f7 }) => {

  $on('pageInit', () => {
    $('.convert-form-to-data').on('click', function () {
      let formData = $f7.form.convertToData('#formDados');
      
      chamarConverterTempo(formData);
    });
  });

  const fecharApp = () => {
    window.close();
  }

  const chamarConverterTempo = async ({minutes, seconds}) => {
    // Chamar a função converter_tempo do Python e esperar pelo resultado
    let total_seconds = await eel.converter_tempo(parseInt(minutes), parseInt(seconds))();

    console.log(total_seconds);
    
    // Exibir o resultado na página
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = 'Total em segundos: ' + total_seconds;
  }

  return $render;
}
</script>

The all log i get in the terminal:
389 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.5.0, contrib hooks: 2024.3
389 INFO: Python: 3.12.2
422 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
425 INFO: wrote C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\app.spec
436 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\workspace\\ConvMinSeg']
806 INFO: checking Analysis
831 INFO: Building because C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_inspect.py changed
831 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
832 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
884 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2624 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2745 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4925 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7666 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7756 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7756 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
7764 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
7764 INFO: Analyzing C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\app.pyw
7778 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-eel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
7808 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
8803 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9032 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10029 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11960 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11974 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12073 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
13842 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
14077 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
15392 INFO: Processing module hooks...
15704 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
16193 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18310 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-distutils.py'.
19303 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19307 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19431 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19779 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
21703 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25636 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools._distutils.command.check.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26027 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26028 INFO: checking Tree
26139 INFO: checking Tree
26165 INFO: checking Tree
26175 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.command.check.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26191 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (978 entries)
31611 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
31659 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
31663 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
31665 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
31668 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook _pyi_rth_utils from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py'.
31673 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
31674 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
31677 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
31681 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_setuptools.py'
31682 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
31717 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
32698 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
32699 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []
33164 INFO: Warnings written to C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\build\app\warn-app.txt
33243 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\build\app\xref-app.html
33311 INFO: checking PYZ
33323 INFO: Building because C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\fake-modules\_pyi_rth_utils\__init__.py changed
33323 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\build\app\PYZ-00.pyz
34333 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\build\app\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
34377 INFO: checking PKG
34391 INFO: Building because toc changed
34392 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) app.pkg
37638 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) app.pkg completed successfully.
37660 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\runw.exe
37661 INFO: checking EXE
37685 INFO: Building because toc changed
37685 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 228, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 212, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1139, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1079, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\workspace\ConvMinSeg\app.spec", line 18, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
          ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 628, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 722, in assemble
    os.remove(self.name)

Obs.:
i try execute as adm and get the same error
I have trying thats tips i get from Copilot:
When using PyInstaller to create an executable from your Python script, you can include additional data files using the --add-data option. This allows you to bundle extra files (such as configuration files, images, or other resources) with your compiled executable. Here are the steps to add data files:

Command Line Approach:

Use the --add-data flag followed by the path to your data file and its destination within the executable. The format is {source}{os_separator}{destination}.
The os_separator is platform-specific: ; on Windows and : on most Unix systems.
Specify the source path to your file(s) and the relative destination folder where they should be placed at runtime.
Examples:

To add a single file named main.kv from the current directory:
pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;." yourtarget.py


To add multiple files:
pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;." --add-data "otherfile.txt;." yourtarget.py






Spec File Approach:

Generate a .spec file by running PyInstaller once (it will create a .spec file for your script).
Edit the .spec file directly to include your data files.
Modify the datas parameter in the .spec file to specify the source and destination for each file.
Example:
a = Analysis(
    ...
    datas=[("main.kv", ".")],
    ...
)





Remember that this approach allows you to bundle additional files into your executable, making it self-contained and portable.
When using PyInstaller to bundle your Python application into an executable, you can include additional data files using the --add-data option. This allows you to package non-binary files (such as configuration files, images, or other resources) along with your executable.
Here are two ways to achieve this:

Command Line Approach:

Add the --add-data parameter followed by the source and destination paths. The format is {source}{os_separator}{destination}.
The os_separator is platform-specific: ; on Windows and : on most Unix systems.
Specify the source path to your file(s) using glob syntax if needed.
The destination folder should be relative to the root where your executable will run, not an absolute path.
Example:
pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;." yourtarget.py




Spec File Approach:

Generate a .spec file by running PyInstaller once (it creates the .spec file automatically).
Edit the .spec file to include your data files.
Modify the datas parameter in the .spec file to specify the source and destination paths.
Example:
a = Analysis(
    ...
    datas=[("main.kv", ".")],
    ...
)





The error you're encountering, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write', typically occurs when PyInstaller or another packaging tool fails to handle certain Python modules or libraries correctly⁵. This issue might be due to the specific version of PyInstaller you're using⁴.
Here are a few potential solutions:

Specify a different version of PyInstaller: You could try uninstalling the current version of PyInstaller and installing a different version. For example, you could use the command pip install pyinstaller==5.4.0³.

Check for buffer-related operations in your code: Look for any operations related to the buffer in your code, such as sys.stdout.flush(), and consider commenting out these lines³.


That last one solution, i dont know where i need to modify:
You can use the pyuac module in your Python script to invoke User Access Control (UAC) in Windows. This allows a Python process to re-spawn a new process with Administrator level rights using the UAC prompt¹. Here's an example of how to use it:
from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin
def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In this example, the @main_requires_admin decorator ensures that your script's main() function will respawn itself as Admin if necessary¹. If you want to capture the stdout and stderr of your Admin sub-process, you can use the decorator like this:
from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin(return_output=True)
def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rv = main()
    if not rv:
        print("I must have already been Admin!")
    else:
        admin_stdout_str, admin_stderr_str, *_ = rv
        if "Do stuff" in admin_stdout_str:
            print("It worked.")

In this case, rv will contain the stdout and stderr of your Admin sub-process¹. You can check these for errors from the non-admin parent¹.
